# Can I change my own mysql password & PMA Problem

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Dear Experts;
I have two questions about of MySQL.

**Q1** : Can I access my own MySQL password when I log in my user password.
**Q2** : My DB Password included space character 
For Example:
mysql://bdr:Part1 211@localhost/bdrdb

I cannot log in PMA using this password information. Why not? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) No, the password is hashed by a oneway-only hashing algorithm, so you cannot read it.

2) What error do you get?

Question in your title) Yes, you can change your password when logged in using the SET PASSWORD command:

> SET PASSWORD =
>   PASSWORD('your-new-password');

Answer (score 2):

That command has new syntax, the old one is deprecated. Try

```
SET PASSWORD = 'your-new-plaintext-password';
```